# i'm trying to use this python script to compare sound but i can't find where to upload them ''source file'' and ''target file''

Tags: python, argparse

i'm new to python and to programming in general, i just need to compare 2 sound files and this script seems to do it but i can't figure out how to upload my .WAV files to this script so please help me

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# compare.py
import argparse
from correlation import correlate

def initialize():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i ", "--source-file", help="source file")
    parser.add_argument("-o ", "--target-file", help="target file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
  
    SOURCE_FILE = args.source_file if args.source_file else None
    TARGET_FILE = args.target_file if args.target_file else None
    if not SOURCE_FILE or not TARGET_FILE:
      raise Exception("Source or Target files not specified.")
    return SOURCE_FILE, TARGET_FILE
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    SOURCE_FILE, TARGET_FILE = initialize()
    correlate(SOURCE_FILE, TARGET_FILE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a program that can be run from the command line. Assuming you already have `python3` installed, you can launch it as

```
python compare.py -h
```

and it will print a help message on how to use it. (This requires you to first navigate to the directory that contains the `compare.py`  file you showed us. That is done with the `cd`  command)

If you place your two sound files in the same directory as the `compare.py`, you can simply specify their names:

```
python compare.py -i sourcefile.wav -o targetfile.wav
```

If the files are not in the same folder, you should write the full path of the files instead.

---

Minor Remark regarding Terminology: I wouldn't call it *uploading* the files to the script. You keep everything local on your computer, nothing is being uploaded. You are trying to *specify the files as command line arguments to the python script*.